# Combining Excel SUMPRODUCT with multi-criteria COUNTIF

Tags: excel, countif, sumproduct

I have a formula which counts unique values and accounts for blanks:

```
"=SUMPRODUCT(((N2:N999<>"")/COUNTIF(N2:N999, N2:N999 &"")))"
```

However, I need this to filter values based on date by cross-referencing from another sheet.

I already have a working formula which crosschecks if date in `C:C` corresponds with a month range within sheet Month.

```
=COUNTIFS(R2:R999, "T", C2:C999,">="&Month!A1, C2:C999,"<="&Month!B1)
```

How do I add/combine criteria `C2:C999,">="&Month!A1, C2:C999,"<="&Month!B1` with the `SUMPRODUCT`/`COUNTIFS` formula above??

Tried everything to get this working but I'm missing some kind of arguments.

Comment: What precisely/all have you tried? What errors do you get about "missing some kind of arguments"?

Comment: try `"=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C999>=Month!A1)*(C2:C999>=Month!B1)*(N2:N999<>"")/COUNTIF(N2:N999, N2:N999 &""))"`